# How to insert table data into another table based on value?

Tags: mysql

I struggle to transfer database table records into another table based on the first table value.
Let me show this -
This is my first table (dr_machine)

| mID | Code | sawing_type | section |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0058 | Zigzag | L01 |
| 2 | 0065 | Zigzag | L01 |
| 3 | 0089 | Puller | L02 |
| 4 | 1124 | Single Needle | L03 |
| 5 | 8796 | Double Needle | L04 |

This is my second table (dr_tv_table)

| sID | L01 | L02 | L03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |

I want to get sawing_type  from the dr_machine table and insert it into to dr_tv_table section-wise.
I tried to accomplish this from a stored procedure and php loop by getting information from other questions in Stackoverflow. but I can't imagine how to do it.

Herewith I attached an image to understand that [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhrBW.jpg) what I am saying.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_into_table(cart_id int )
BEGIN 
DECLARE i int default 1 ;

while(i<10)      
Do
   insert into dr_tv_table (i
                ) 
   select  `sawing_type`

   from dr_machinewhere section='L01' ;
   set i=i+1;
   END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: A).what's the point of just copying from one table to another? It's just duplication for no reason. B) why do you think you need a loop? Insert...select syntax will work fine on its own if you just write it correctly. C) there's no php code here

Comment: You seem to be trying to create something which should maybe be handled in your user interface rather than in data storage

Comment: I am trying to display html table from it. is there any way to do that without creating another table?

Comment: Yeah, just use php to select the original data, put it into an array, and then you can build absolutely any display you wish from that array, if you write the code

Comment: `...from dr_machinewhere...` - that will throw an error, there needs to be a space before `where`

Comment: Pretty sure this has been posted before under a different op name. I'm still don't know why some sections appear in desired outcome and some don't - in this case why does L01-L03 appear and L04 does not? And how is it that you get L01-L03 to appear when the published query specifically selects where section  = L01?

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3. PS. I doubt that you need in copying to the static table, single query should be enough. PPS. Search SO by the term "pivot".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data

```
CREATE TABLE dr_machine(
   mID           INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,Code          INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,sawing_Type VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  ,section       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO dr_machine
(mID,Code,sawing_Type,section) VALUES 
(1,0058,'Zigzag','L01'),
(2,0065,'Zigzag','L01'),
(3,0089,'Puller','L02'),
(4,1124,'Single Needle','L03'),
(5,8796,'Double Needle','L04');
```

use `Max`, `Group By` and `Case`

```
SELECT
mID,  
MAX(CASE WHEN (section='L01') THEN sawing_Type ELSE '' END) AS L01,
MAX(CASE WHEN (section='L02') THEN sawing_Type ELSE '' END) AS L02,
MAX(CASE WHEN (section='L03') THEN sawing_Type ELSE '' END) AS L03,
MAX(CASE WHEN (section='L04') THEN sawing_Type ELSE '' END) AS L04
FROM 
dr_machine
GROUP BY 
mID
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vpt6l4Gv)

Comment: Hi, it's working fine.But I want to hide null (empty) cells. how can I do that?

Comment: replace NULL with ''